# Need help with "need help" questions

Tags: support, questions

Plz help!

I  really need help with [all those "need help"](https://superuser.com/search?tab=newest&q=title:%22need%20help%22) posts!1 (<s>x86</s> 36)

It's really urgent.

---

No, seriously. The words "need help" in a title are a good sign of low quality posts. In most cases, the OP had an urgent issue to fix or didn't bother to perform basic research.

I believe these questions need cleaning up. If someone wants to help go through them, here's what needs to be done:

- **Fix the title**. Mention what the real issue at hand is. See: [How do I write a good title?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10647/how-do-i-write-a-good-title)
- **Look at the body**. Spelling errors, capitalization errors, redundant "Hi / Thanks" or other signatures, info only found in comments, etc.
- **Add proper tags**.

And, finally:

- **Vote to close** (if you have ≥3k) or **flag** them for attention if they're not a good fit for the site. Or post them in the [VTC chatroom](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/117/super-user-vote-to-close-delete).
- <s>**Delete** [already closed posts](https://superuser.com/search?q=title:%22need%20help%22%20closed:1&submit=search) (this would be one for the mods).</s>  – done, cheers!

Please don't edit all at once, but make it in batches of 10 questions or so.

Comment: I will start editing some of them later that day.

Comment: You forgot to start the post with *"So, I "*

Comment: +1 And we're down to 60.

Comment: Looking for experts!!! I've just done 5 edits bringing us below 50.

Comment: **Related:** http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/122203/please-add-need-help-as-a-filter-for-titles

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Done.

(at least for now).

Not sure why I took special interest in this cleanup task, but I've done my bit and got it down to zero (as of 13th Feb).

[image: got it to zero]

Comment: That's awesome, thank you very much!

Answer (score 4):

This is an ongoing problem, one that we can deal with by keeping an eye out for these questions and editing them to make them clearer, more concise, and just plain easier to read.

Keep up the good work!

Comment: need help **dog pee'd on PC**... the pick of the litter for this cleanup, I kept the dog pee out of the title. http://superuser.com/questions/226305/need-help-toubleshooting-pc